# How to get Cumulative count since month begin in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID              int(11)       (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)            
CREATED_DATE    datetime      (NULL)             YES             (NULL)
```

---

As mentioned above is some of field of my table 'User'.I want number of total user and cumulative count grouped on date.I used below query in mysql.

```
SELECT q1.CREATED_DATE,q1.NO_OF_USER, (@runtot := @runtot + q1.NO_OF_USER) AS   CUMM_REGISTRATION FROM (SELECT date(CREATED_DATE) AS CREATED_DATE,
   COUNT(ID) AS NO_OF_USER FROM  USER,(SELECT @runtot:=0) AS n GROUP  BY CREATED_DATE ORDER  BY CREATED_DATE) AS q1
```

Which is working fine.Now I want one more additional data which will be 'CUMULATIVE USER COUNT SINCE 1 AUGUST '.Is it possible to fetch this modifying above query or its better to handle in code?Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding another variable and doing it in the code:

```
SELECT q1.CREATED_DATE, q1.NO_OF_USER,
       (@runtot := @runtot + q1.NO_OF_USER) AS CUMM_REGISTRATION,
       @Aug1tot := if(CREATED_DATE >=date('2013-08-01'), @Aug1tot + q1.NO_OF_USER, NULL) as CUMM_SINCE_Aug1
FROM (SELECT date(CREATED_DATE) AS CREATED_DATE,
             COUNT(ID) AS NO_OF_USER
      FROM  USER cross join
            (SELECT @runtot:=0, @Aug1tot := 0) n
      GROUP  BY date(CREATED_DATE)
      ORDER  BY date(CREATED_DATE);
     ) AS q1
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer,but there seems an error.No of user is always shown as 1 whereas CUMM_SINCE_Aug1 returns null if CREATED_DATE is less than 1st august.

Comment: @sandy . . . The changes for the new variable should not affect the value of `NO_OF_USER`.  And, yes, it does return `NULL` for early dates.  That is intentional because of the definition of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some function called MONTH(yourDate) in mySQL, where MONTH(15-Aug-2013) will return 8.

You could either group your results per MONTH(yourDate), or filter your original data for MONTH(yourDate) = 8. Be careful if your data runs along multiple years, as all dates where month = 8 will be cumulated. You could then add a sorting / filtering critera based on YEAR(yourDate)